# Using map in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the `map` Python function (I know I can use list comprehension but I was instructed to use map in this example) to take the row average of a two row matrix.

Here is what I think the answer should look like:

```
def average_rows2(mat):
    print( map( float(sum) / len , [mat[0],mat[1]] ) )
average_rows2([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]])
```

Right now, only the sum function works:

```
def average_rows2(mat):
    print( map( sum , [mat[0],mat[1]] ) )
average_rows2([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]])
```

The first problem is that adding the `float()` to the sum function gives the error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Which is weird because the elements of the resulting list should be integers since it successfully calculates the sum.

Also, adding `/ len` to the sum function gives this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

For this error, I tried `*` and `//` and it says that none are supported operand types. I don't understand why none of these would be supported.

Maybe this means that the `map` function doesn't take composite functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first argument has to be evaluated before it can be passed to `map`. This:

```
float(sum) / len
```

is causing you various errors as it doesn't make any sense to evaluate it on its own (unless you'd shadowed `sum` and `len`, which would be a different problem). You are trying to sum over one built-in function then divide by another! It therefore cannot be an argument.

Instead, make a function, e.g.:

```
lambda lst: float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)
```

This is a callable with a single argument, therefore can be used as the first argument to `map`, which will then apply it to each element in its second argument. You could also use a regular function, rather than an anonymous `lambda` (as now shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34831192/3001761).

Answer (score 0):

This will work regardless of how many rows there are:

```
def average_rows(m):
    return map(lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l)), m)
print average_rows([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]]) # [4.75, 6.25]
```

The function returns a list that's the result of applying the lambda to each element (row) of `m`.

The [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)  `lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l))` is basically a function that takes a list and returns the average of its elements as a float. You could assign it to a variable and call it like a regular function:

```
avg = lambda l: sum(l) / float(len(l))
print avg([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

What `map` does is apply a given function to each element of a list. In your case, I think it's clearer to define this function (to calculate the average of a single row) separately, like so:

```
def average_of_one_row(r):
    return float(sum(r)) / len(r)

def average_of_each_row(mat):
    return map(average_of_one_row, mat)

print average_of_rows([[4, 5, 2, 8], [3, 9, 6, 7]])
```